# DataTables Bootstrap and jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm trying to use [DataTables Bootstrap](http://www.datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap_2/) together with jQuery ui. Inside of my table cells I have hyperlinks what are opening dialog modal boxes to edit different input fields to be send to database. On table load this actions are firing properly but if use the sorting or pagination function of the table this are breaking and I get the raw Html output.
The table is getting initialized with the following

```
/* Table initialisation */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span8'l><'span12'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        },

        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                {
                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                    "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

than in another js file I'm trying to catch jquery ui events

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dialog = $('#tabs').tabs(
                    {

                        select: function(ev, ui) {

                            //Setup Buttons to each Tab
                            switch(ui.index) {
                            case 0:
                                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button").show().filter(":contains('Email senden')").hide(); 
                            break;

                            case 1:
                                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button").show().filter(":contains('Speichern')").hide(); 
                            break;

                            case 2:
                                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button").hide(); 
                            break;

                        }

                      }        
                }).dialog({ //codes});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change a few things:

1. Consider using [Bootstrap's built in modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) window instead of the jQuery UI dialog window. I've found a couple situations where Bootstrap and jQuery UI don't work very well together. If you can remove the jQuery UI dependency, so much the better.
2. Use [DataTable's `mData` property](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns#mData) with a function in your column definitions to dynamically create the link/button that triggers the modal window. This way when your data is sorted/filtered it won't break the trigger that launches the window.

Quick example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": [ 0 ],
      "mData": function ( source, type, val ) {
        return "<button data-id='" + source.my-id + "' class='edit-button btn'>Edit</button>";
      }
    } ]
  } );

  $(document).on('click', '.edit-button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(e.target).data('id');
    $("#MyModal").modal();
  });
} );
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I'm going to start to refactor my codes a bit to try out your suggestion.

Comment: returning to this issue after couple of weeks I have the following problem. I can get the value of source.id. This should be the first cell of each column. If I alert the hole source I see the retrieved datas